# How to recover contents of Home folder

Tags: data-recovery, home-directory

My old computer crashed. I now have a new computer and I wanted to retrieve contents of the HDD of the old computer.

So I connected the old HDD to new computer. I see its folders, but they are mostly empty. Home folder is empty as well. The drive also contains a 2Gb file named swapfile.

- Is it possible that I just don't see the contents of the Home folder? Because of some user rights issue or smth like that? If so, how can I see the contents?
- Is it possible that due to crash the files may be somewhere else (for instance, in this huge swapfile)? If so, how can I recover them? And if not, where else can they be?

Comment: Or your home folder was on a separate partition?

Comment: no, I had only one partition on old HDD

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk` with the old drive plugged in?

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible that I just don't see the contents of the Home folder? Because of some user rights issue or something like that? If so, how can I see the contents?

In your new computer, if you use nautilus as root (e.g. type `sudo -H nautilus` on terminal) you can see all files. Try opening your old home folder this way, if there is some file in there, it will appear.

[image: Nautilus Elevated Perms]

Comment: Tried nautilus, the folder is still empty.

Comment: If no folders/files under home using `sudo nautilus` then its gone.

Answer (score 2):

OK, problem solved. I just didn't know I have to approach the `/home/` folder in the hard drive of my previous computer via `/media/` folder of the current computer's hard drive.

Thanks for advices, you helped me closer to solution!